# The random variable X has moment generating function. Compute $E(X)$

Tags: probability, expectation

The random variable X has moment generating function

$$m_X(t) = \frac{6}{\sqrt{(1-t)(4-t)(9-t)}}$$

for $t < 1$

Compute $E(X)$

Solution:

This can be rewritten to:

$m_X(t) = \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^{1/2} \cdot \left(\frac{4}{4-t}\right)^{1/2} \cdot \left(\frac{9}{9-t}\right)^{1/2} $

Having the distribution of $Gamma(\alpha = 1, \lambda  = 1/2), Gamma(\alpha = 4, \lambda  = 1/2), Gamma(\alpha = 9, \lambda  = 1/2)$

Since Gamma has $E(X) = \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} = 0.5/1 + 0.5/4 + 0.5/9 = 49/72$

---

I have a few questions about this solution.

Isn't $E(X) = m'_X(0)$?

And I thought the gamma distribution was

$Gamma(a, b) = \frac{b^a x^{a-1} e^{-bx}}{\Gamma{(a)}}$ for $x > 0$

not $Gamma(\alpha = 1, \lambda  = 1/2) = \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^{1/2}$

Could someone help me understand this please.

Comment: The term $(1-t)^{-1/2}$ is the MGF of a Gamma distribution, not the PDF. You can calculate the expected value via the derivative but it is slightly laborious even with logarithmic differentiation. It is just easier to use the property that for independent $X,Y$, $M_{X+Y}(t) = M_{X}(t)M_{Y}(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment generating function of $Gamma(\alpha = 1, \lambda = \frac12) = \left( \frac1{1-t}\right)^\frac12$, what you have written is the pdf.

There is more than one method to solve the problem.

Their method has identified $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$ where each $X_i$ is a gamma distribution of which we know their mean and to find the expectation of $X$, we just have to sum of expectation of each $X_i$.